# How to display specific button for certain user?

Tags: 7, theming

I have a simple Drupal 7 page with 3 buttons. Page is only accessible by logged-in users.

I have 3 roles - role 1, role 2 & role 3

What I would like to do is to show only **button 1** when a user with **role 1** logged in, hide the other 2.
How can I achieve this, please?

Answer (score 0):

To hide and show buttons by role you can use the ***$GLOBALS*** to get the user and check on user role, something like.

```
 <?php if (in_array('role 1', $GLOBALS["user"]->roles)): ?>
    <button value="button 1">button 1</button>
  <?php else: ?>
    <button value="button 2">button 2</button>
    <button value="button 3">button 3</button>
  <?php endif; ?>
```